# How can I do a Search and replace in Microsoft OneNote?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2013, microsoft-onenote-2016

I cannot find the search and replace function in Microsoft OneNote. <kbd>Ctrl+H</kbd> does not work. Not existing or hidden? I have OneNote 15, please help me to find out which version this corresponds to to get the correct tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OneNote 15 is OneNote 2013. I believe there is no specific search and replace function in OneNote 2013, but Microsoft has the following suggestion. First, copy the replacement text to the clipboard. `Ctrl-E` expands the search box so that you can **pin search results** to the bottom of the results. Then you can click on each search result in the list to select it, and paste your replacement text over it.

Quoting [Microsoft's support page](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Find-and-replace-text-in-notes-34b1f7f8-d327-40c5-8b0c-8419425ed68b)

> 1.On a blank page, type the replacement text that you want to use. For example, if you’re trying to update a project name in your notes, type
>   the new project name.
>
> 2.Select the text you just typed, and then press Ctrl+C to copy it to the clipboard.
>
> 3.Press Ctrl+E to expand the search box in the top right corner of the OneNote window.
>
> 4.In the search box, type the text you want to find.
>
> 5.At the bottom of the results list, click Pin Search Results, or press Ctrl+O.
>
> 6.In the Search Results pane on the right side of your window, click the first search result (blue link next to a white page icon) to jump
>   to the page where OneNote highlighted the text it has found.
>
> 7.On the page, double-click each highlighted occurrence of the text, and then press Ctrl+V to paste your replacement text over it.
>
> 8.Repeat steps 6-7 for each additional page in the search results list.

Comment: Same applies to OneNote 2016 as well. There is no real Search/Replace

Comment: That's pretty pathetic Microsoft.

Comment: Onetastic has an [add-on for OneNote](https://getonetastic.com/macroland&id=20F029487157446B81830EAA645A2214) that allows search/replace within a page

Answer (score 4):

I am using a variance of the solution from Microsoft (as given by Andrew). Which  might be better if all your words are on the same page and you have multiple words to "search and replace".

1. Press <kbd>Cltr+F</kbd> to search in page, type the text you want to find.
2. On a random spot of your page, type the replacement text that you want to use.
3. Select the text you just typed, and then press <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> to cut it to the clipboard.
4. You should see two arrows *(blue arrow yellow background)* at the left of the search text box, press on either one of the arrow.
5. You should see your text highlighted, press <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> to paste your replacement text over it
6. Repeat `step 4-5` until all text is replaced.

> Bam! 2 steps less than official requirement.

*P.s. I heard that Onetastic (https://getonetastic.com/) will help add the "search and replace" feature to OneNote, but it is not a solution to me since I am using OneNote on a company computer.*

Answer (score 2):

I find the solution in the official support document difficult, and don't understand why MS don't make the universal-ish `Ctrl + H` available for OneNote..
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-and-replace-text-in-notes-34b1f7f8-d327-40c5-8b0c-8419425ed68b

What I'm doing currently is to open a new Outlook mail or Word doc or whatever (*please don't start "the OP is asking about **OneNote** not xxx", and then downvote, like in the `JavaScript`/`jQuery` questions, only trying to help here... lol*), and paste the snippet there, and do the `Ctrl + H` work the way you are used to  : )

Answer (score 1):

The best method I found was to do a `Ctrl + F` to find something on a page and then press `F3` to cycle through every hit pressing `Ctrl + V` to replace them.